# Unable to add new version for any App Store Connect app

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

It is currently not feasible to generate a new version for any application on the App Store Connect. To replicate this issue, I go to my app and select the (+) button to initiate the creation of a new version number. After entering a version number, I proceed to click "Create." However, the process encounters an error, displaying the message, "An error has occurred. Please try again later."